# Do i need a cert for this php redirect to work as i'm expecting it to?

Tags: php, redirect, ssl, curl, https

When I access **http**`://www.google.com/` in my browser I'm redirected to **https**`://www.google.com/`. I'm expecting `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` to return me **https** when running this code:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://google.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
echo curl_exec($ch); // echos nothing
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // echos '200'
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); // echos 'http://google.com/'
curl_close($ch);
```

Will adding a ssl cert and adding the following fields make this work as i'm expecting?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'whateverCrt.crt');
```

Comment: What does this code currently return?

Comment: `curl_exec($ch);` return nothing (literally blank), `CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE` returns `200`, and `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` returns `http://google.com/`